# Ubuntu Crashes, where do I look to fix it?

Tags: 11.10

My ubuntu laptop crashes with a bunch of code on the screen.  Where can I look to see what is causing the crash?

Comment: We'd need to see that "bunch of code on the screen" to tell you what's going on

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travis, start your PC with the LiveCD and follow the instructions of this post:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=49925

Remember that your **/etc/default/bootlogd** will be into your Ubuntu partition, when you're inside the LiveCD. Will be something like **/media/[Disk-1-LABEL]/etc/default/bootlogd**.

After that, put here your **/var/log/boot** contents.

--

Travis, I think that your bug is related here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/875571

By this way, you could try to update your kernel to the 3.1 version.

You can get the update to Kernel 3.1.4 here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.1.4-oneiric/

Comment: The crash I am having is not during boot.  It boots up fine, I will be using ubuntu, and suddenly black screen with a ton of text about modules and panic and everything is locked up.  I can't go to the console, I can't restart, I have to hold in the power button until it shuts off.  I would think there would be a file somewhere that all that code was being written to that would say "This module failed" or something like that.  Is there?

Comment: Looks like Kernel issues, try with 10.04

Comment: Travis, just look to my edited answer to see if it fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my Toshiba laptop and Ubuntu 11.10. I reinstalled several times, and only when I disable the update settings and thereby using the original code from the boot CD I save my laptop from crashing within minutes after booting...
Probably it is a kernel or graphic driver issue but it should be addressed!